# Creating npm package for React Native Component

Tags: react-native, npm, webpack

I am trying to create a react native component npm package following:

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-publish-a-react-native-component-to-npm-its-easier-than-you-think-51f6ae1ef850/

but I do not understand at which step the npm package is created. Can I create the package and test its installation before publishing it to npm?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The npm package is created at beginning of article.
To test it, in an application you can add your package with `yarn add file:path_relative_component`.
But I don't have the 'tips' to test it without lost a lot of time with delete node_modules folder and execute command. See [Develop own NPM package for react-native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66308438/develop-own-npm-package-for-react-native)